# express:- altering req.session of another user

Tags: node.js, session, express

Does `req.session` reside at the server? can i change `req.session` of another user at the server based on parameters?

If there a variable where `req.session` reside at the server end, which can be browsed for parameter match.

```
for(i in reqArray){
 if(reqArray[i].session._id === 'abc') {
   // do something 
 }
}
```

is `req` a completely client side variable, which cannot be influenced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req.session` is a server side variable created by Connect, which is extended by Express. Documentation, including an example of a user-specific view counter, is here: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html